# Rust, getting values from HashMap with enum

Tags: rust, enums, hashmap

I'm trying make one HashMap with different types. I don't want to make two different HashMaps for specific data types.

My code is bellow:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum DataTypes {
    String(String),
    Bool(bool),
}

fn get_hashmap() -> Result<HashMap<String, DataTypes>, ()>{
    let data = HashMap::from([
        ("password".to_string(), DataTypes::String("password".to_string())),
        ("username".to_string(), DataTypes::String("Fun username".to_string())),
        ("is_blocked".to_string(), DataTypes::Bool(true)),
        ("is_confirmed".to_string(), DataTypes::Bool(false)),
    ]);
    Ok(data)
}
fn main() {
    let data = get_hashmap().unwrap();
    let keys = data.keys();
    println!("Keys: {:?}", &keys);
    for key in keys {
        let result: Option<T> = match data.get(key).unwrap() {
            DataTypes::Bool(value) => Some(value),
            DataTypes::String(value) => Some(value),
            _ => panic!("Error!"),
        };
        println!("Result of matching: {:?}", &result);
    }
}
```

Like you can see I'm trying to maching Enums to getting their values. But i have some problem of data types.
My solution for this is wrap result of matching to Some struct. But still main problem is not resolved.

So I want to make result of matching in Option class to make available unwrap().
But I don't know how i can do that correctly...

I have two question:

1. Can i do this better?
2. How can I wrap let result: Option to working state?

Comment: What do you want to do with `result`? They're different types.

Comment: I want to send this values to database. Before sending data to database I want to serialize result to User struct.

Comment: Then why cannot you serialize them inside the `match`?

Comment: Or just serialize the enum directly (for serde, `#[derive(Serialize)] #[serde(untagged)]` on the enum).

Comment: Good point, for now I don't know how to do that, but I think is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some feedback:

- Don't include a `_` default match case if you already handle all the options. It will hide future errors.
- Don't name a variable `DataTypes` if every member is only a single datatype. Name it `DataType`.
- `result` has to be a specific type. The whole point of the enum is that you can handle the different values separately, so combining them in a `result` type is pointless. Although you of course **can** keep `result` a `DataType` object and implement `Debug`/`Display` for it, which is how I will do it in my reworked code.
- While you **can** query the key first and then again query the value in the loop, this is quite slow. You can iterate over key-value pairs right away. That way you avoid a lot of `unwrap()`s, which makes your code a lot less error-prone.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum DataType {
    String(String),
    Bool(bool),
}

fn get_hashmap() -> Result<HashMap<String, DataType>, ()> {
    let data = HashMap::from([
        (
            "password".to_string(),
            DataType::String("password".to_string()),
        ),
        (
            "username".to_string(),
            DataType::String("Fun username".to_string()),
        ),
        ("is_blocked".to_string(), DataType::Bool(true)),
        ("is_confirmed".to_string(), DataType::Bool(false)),
    ]);
    Ok(data)
}
fn main() {
    let data = get_hashmap().unwrap();
    for (key, value) in data {
        println!("{}: {:?}", key, value);

        match value {
            DataType::Bool(value) => {
                println!("\tValue was a bool: {}", value);
                // do something if the value is a bool
            }
            DataType::String(value) => {
                println!("\tValue was a string: {}", value);
                // do something if the value is a string,
            } /*
               * Don't include a default case. That way the compiler
               * will remind you to handle additional enum entries if
               * you add them in the future.
               * Adding a default case is only a good practice in languages
               * where matching is not exhaustive.
               */
        };
    }
}
```

```
username: String("Fun username")
        Value was a string: Fun username
is_confirmed: Bool(false)
        Value was a bool: false
is_blocked: Bool(true)
        Value was a bool: true
password: String("password")
        Value was a string: password
```

---

Don't worry though, you don't need to use `match` everywhere you use this enum, otherwise you wouldn't win much compared to two separate hashmaps. You can, instead, define shared functionality for all enum entries, and hide the `match` inside of it. Like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum DataType {
    String(String),
    Bool(bool),
}

impl DataType {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        match self {
            DataType::Bool(value) => {
                println!("\tDo something with boolean '{}'!", value);
            }
            DataType::String(value) => {
                println!("\tDo something with string {:?}!", value);
            }
        };
    }
}

fn get_hashmap() -> Result<HashMap<String, DataType>, ()> {
    let data = HashMap::from([
        (
            "password".to_string(),
            DataType::String("password".to_string()),
        ),
        (
            "username".to_string(),
            DataType::String("Fun username".to_string()),
        ),
        ("is_blocked".to_string(), DataType::Bool(true)),
        ("is_confirmed".to_string(), DataType::Bool(false)),
    ]);
    Ok(data)
}

fn main() {
    let data = get_hashmap().unwrap();
    for (key, value) in data {
        println!("{}: {:?}", key, value);
        value.do_something();
    }
}
```

```
is_confirmed: Bool(false)
        Do something with boolean 'false'!
password: String("password")
        Do something with string "password"!
is_blocked: Bool(true)
        Do something with boolean 'true'!
username: String("Fun username")
        Do something with string "Fun username"!
```

---

If your goal is to add serialization/deserialization to your struct (as you seem to implement manually here), let me hint you towards [`serde`](https://serde.rs), which already takes care of the majority of serialization for free.

Like in this example (which may or may not be how your struct looks like) that serializes your struct to and from JSON:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct User {
    username: String,
    password: String,
    is_blocked: bool,
    is_confirmed: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let user = User {
        username: "Fun username".to_string(),
        password: "password".to_string(),
        is_blocked: true,
        is_confirmed: false,
    };

    let user_serialized = serde_json::to_string(&user).unwrap();
    println!("Serialized: {}", user_serialized);

    let user_deserialized: User = serde_json::from_str(&user_serialized).unwrap();
    println!("Name: {}", user_deserialized.username);
}
```

```
Serialized: {"username":"Fun username","password":"password","is_blocked":true,"is_confirmed":false}
Name: Fun username
```

Comment: Thanks for good feedback. It's really helpful :) I need agreed with you in all points.
Combining all DataTypes in one result has one strong reason.

I need to use it to send this output to database. I have much more complicated User stucture with Option<T> properties.

I want to avoid calling matching to every entry in HashMap and get value from Enum. But know I can see the simpler method is used to two HashMaps with different datatypes. Much less complicated.

Comment: This trick with unpack hashmap in for loop is great! Thanks :)

Comment: @RfDzDeveloper I don't fully agree, I think using the enum is fine. You can implement shared behaviour where you hide the match statements in the implementation. See the added section in my answer.

Comment: I think this is great answer! I can understand now clear what happened and what I can do with that. Big, Big thanks for your time and explaining to me this concept.

Comment: @RfDzDeveloper But ChayimFriedman is right, if your problem concerns Serialization/Deserialization, the majority of the work in Rust is already taken care of if you use [`serde`](https://serde.rs/). Although doing it manually is probably also a good exercise to improve your programming skills.

Comment: @RfDzDeveloper Added a third section to showcase how serde might work with your struct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Finomnis** I found way what I'm looking for.
This is my scratch solution.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum DataType {
    String(String),
    Bool(bool),
}

impl DataType {
    fn get_bool(&self) -> bool {
        let result = match self {
            DataType::Bool(value) => value.to_owned(),
            _ => panic!("Something"),
        };
        result
    }

    fn get_string(&self) -> String {
        let result = match self {
            DataType::String(value) => value.to_owned(),
            _ => panic!("Something"),
        };
        result
    }
}

fn get_hashmap() -> Result<HashMap<String, DataType>, ()>{
    let data = HashMap::from([
        ("password".to_string(), DataType::String("password".to_string())),
        ("username".to_string(), DataType::String("Fun username".to_string())),
        ("is_blocked".to_string(), DataType::Bool(true)),
        ("is_confirmed".to_string(), DataType::Bool(false)),
    ]);
    Ok(data)
}

fn main() {
    // now we can simply get values from hashmap
    let mut my_hash_map = get_hashmap().unwrap();
    let username = my_hash_map.remove("username").unwrap().get_string();
    let is_blocked = my_hash_map.remove("is_blocked").unwrap().get_bool();

    // Now we have clear value of username and is_blocked.
    println!("{}", username);
    println!("{}", is_blocked);
}
```

I think this can be helpful when we are want using Databases. When we don't want serialize all User structure.

Probably this can be done much better.
Again thanks all for BIG help! :)